# Android Alert Dialog Text Align

Tags: android, dialog, alert

How To Align Right Order Total Values Like Below Images.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Please add the layout xml. It will be easier to give you tips on what you can do.

Comment: No Xml Layout Just AlertDialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below links

[link1](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-dialog-example)

[link2](http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-display-custom-dialog-and.html)

Answer (score 0):

For each row use the following style in xml.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:text="Label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView 
        android:text="Value"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

You can use the height width of the linear layout as your wish