# how to make a string keep straight?

Tags: java, android

```
    Button hoursButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hours);
    final AlertDialog.Builder openinghours = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);


    hoursButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openinghours.setTitle("Opening Hours");
            openinghours.setMessage(
                      "\nMonday:         CLOSED"
                    + "\nTuesday:        CLOSED"
                    + "\nWednesday:   22:00 - 3:00"
                    + "\nThursday:       CLOSED"
                    + "\nFriday:             22:00 - 3:00"
                    + "\nSaturday:        22:00 - 3:00"
                    + "\nSunday:           CLOSED");
            openinghours.setPositiveButton("OK", 
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }


                    });
```

The opening hours are displayed. I want the actual opening hours to be displayed in a neat straight line, this is how it displays:

[image]

i'm trying to space the string out so that it looks all in straight, formed line.

There must be a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an xml-document for the dialog you could align the text using gravity.

Further reading: [Alert dialog aligning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450699/android-alert-dialog-text-align)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create an XML layout and create a table.

I know this isnt the code but I dont have my ide open

```
<table>

<row><row>Monday</row><row>CLOSED</row></row>
<row><row>Tuesday</row><row>CLOSED</row></row>

</table>
```

Then you will need to set the layout when creating the alert.